# JQuery Selector get the ID at the end of the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some DIVs which represent buttons, all the button as the following ID structure:

```
Button_<id>
```

Example:

```
Button_54
```

Is there a way to attach a click listener to all the button and get its ID inside the listener? I came up with the following solution, but I don't think it is the way to do so... Do you have any suggestion?

```
$('[id$="Button_"]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var ButtonID = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("Button_"));
    //.
    //. Do somthing which requires the ID
    //. of this button, for instance an AJAX request
    //.
});
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to give all the buttons their own class, then use that to apply the handler.

Comment: Yes, I can do it but an ID should be unique, I just want to know what a good practice solution is.

Comment: He'talking about classes not id's. A common class to select the buttons. But your code is okay...

Comment: @KirillKulakov Apart from ID Lee Taylor suggests you to add `class` attribute, which isn't required to be unique.

Comment: I already use the class parameter to define the style of the button, having multiple classes could be an option by probably not the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Attribute Ends With selector, which doesn't select your elements, you should use Attribute Starts With selector instead:

```
$('[id^="Button_"]').click(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/g).join(''); // 54
    // ....

});
```

Comment: `.match` gives an array, though.

Comment: Alternative could be to use the original code but modify to `...lastIndexOf("_") + 1...`, assuming all IDs will be in the same format and the unique bit will only ever be after the last underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
    $('[id^="button_"]').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ButtonID = id.split('_')[1];
        alert(ButtonID);
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VSg9/)